# Laravel route is not accepting id parameter in array format anymore

Tags: laravel

We used several named routes in blade files but for some reason the id is not recognized anymore:

```
{{ route('fields.edit', ['id' => $id])}}
```

When i rewrite it to

```
{{ route('fields.edit', $id)}}
```

the error

```
Missing required parameters for [Route: fields.edit]
```

the route is defined like this:

```
Route::resource('fields', 'WebfieldController', ['except' => 'destroy']);
```

is gone.

Any idea what im overlooking?

hopefully someone can help us out since we used it this way in many places...

thnx

Comment: Show us your route's definition, please. If it's something like `fields/{field}` your route parameter would need to be named `field`, not `id`.

Comment: Please share your route for this ?

Comment: same happened to me after some updates, now i place it in array [ $this->id ], and make sure $Field->id is not null, or not in $hidden

Comment: thnx for the comments, the id is valid and when it is not inside the array it is working without any errors. only when i re-introduce the array brackets i get the error message...

Answer (score 0):

If you consult `php artisan route:list`, you'll find that your route parameter is not named `id`, but `field`. It'll look like this:

```
fields/{field}
```

As such, you have to do this:

```
{{ route('fields.edit', ['field' => $id])}}
```

You can pass in the ID, or the whole Field model.

Comment: thnx, but the parameter is named id.

Comment: Not if you did `Route::resource('fields', ...)`, it's not. Check `php artisan route:list`, @Basdrum88.

Comment: ahhh you are completely right, am sorry. Is this since an update or something? it used to be $id if im not mistaken? Normally it worked like that.

Comment: @Basdrum88 `Route::resource` has always worked this way, to my knowledge. Perhaps you switched to resource controllers from manually created routes?